# How to find packages for a Delphi 2007 project without a bpl file?

Tags: delphi, include, package

I've programmed before in PHP, Java and C(#), but I'm new to Delphi. I installed Delphi 2007 and opened a project I got (and which actually has a request for change) by it's .dpr file and had to click away over a dozen messages of errors.
When I opened the first .pas file I saw a lot of red underlined words (actually 16) in the uses section. I found out these are all part of packages (a bit like jars one can include in a java application), but these packages are not part of the project and have to be separately downloaded and installed. I took one of the 16 missing includes, found the package for it, downloaded and installed it and now I'm at 15 red underlined includes.

As not all the Delphi packages I need are easy to find and it might be that other source files need even more packages I first wanted to have a complete list of packages I need. I did find [Determining Delphi Runtime Packages to Include](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1562601/determining-delphi-runtime-packages-to-include) but that relies on a .bpl file, which I don't have. Unfortunately after building (and clicking away a lot of error messages again) I don't get information either 'cause there's no View item under Project. I downloaded Required from Bob Swart, but that ain't helping either as I simply can't get a bpl file when I only have the source of a project and it will not compile or build because of the missing packages. That kinda sucks and actually seems to me like a design flaw of Delphi ...

So, is there another way to find out all the packages I need? And is there a way to find those packages easily? For instance is there a website that has them all??

For example how can I find out which package I need for ComPort as there probably are dozens with that name? Java luckily always has an include structure like net.somewhere.blah/ComPort, but Delphi doesn't seem to know where a used file comes from unless the .bpl file is around, or does it?

Comment: When Delphi 3 was released in 1997 hardly any other RAD tool had even that support for packages. Today it really lags behind...  Now, search for *.DPK files in your project, those are sources for packages to compile and maybe also to INSTALL into IDE. In those sources you would also find REQUIRES section to find even more packages. For EXE/DPR in the Project Options there is "runtime packages" section where if your sourcees are complete you would also find a list of runtime packages

Comment: Actually, the Delphi IDE more depends of half-compiled templates *.DCP rather than *.BPL // In Delphi 4 - 7 you could open DPK project, and open "requires" tree and dbl-click on those dependences to open those packages too (and even if DPK sources would be missed, Delphi did reversed them from DCP) but in D2005 they broken it and it never worked since :-(

Comment: Unfortunately no "runtime packages" in my dpr file (not much to see when I open it in Notepad++). There are three dcp files, two of them with D2006 in their filename and one with D2007. That package I can install, but it's the only one, so still 14 includes to go ...

Comment: A do find a dproj file with a list though, and that's long, very long ....:

Comment: It doesn't even fit at once; part 1: rtl;vcl;dbrtl;vcldb;vclx;adortl;dbxcds;dbexpress;vclib;ibxpress;IntrawebDB_72_90;Intraweb_72_90;xmlrtl;vclie;inet;inetdbbde;inetdbxpress;IndySystem;IndyCore;dclOffice2k;VclSmp;soaprtl;dsnap;IndyProtocols;inetdb;bdertl;vcldbx;vclactnband;vclshlctrls;O407_r90;A407_R90;B305vr2005;K102_R2005

Comment: part 2: ;DJcl;JvStdCtrlsD9R;JvAppFrmD9R;JvCoreD9R;JvBandsD9R;JvBDED9R;JvDBD9R;JvDlgsD9R;JvCmpD9R;JvCryptD9R;JvCtrlsD9R;JvCustomD9R;JvDockingD9R;JvDotNetCtrlsD9R;JvEDID9R;JvGlobusD9R;JvHMID9R;JvInspectorD9R;JvInterpreterD9R;JvJansD9R;JvManagedThreadsD9R;JvMMD9R;JvNetD9R;JvPageCompsD9R;JvPluginD9R;JvPrintPreviewD9R;JvSystemD9R;JvTimeFrameworkD9R;JvUIBD9R;JvValidatorsD9R;JvWizardD9R;JvXPCtrlsD9R;Rz252D2005;Rz252N2005;iocomp2005;TeeGL57;S403_r70;S403br70;S403bd70;numericedit

Comment: Looks like somebody puked a load of 3rd party guff on the project and you are left cleaning up the mess. You might like to talk to the original author who may have some information.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan regarding "puked a load of 3rd party guff" hopefulyl those are jsut dependencies added "for any case", like for example JVCL DB-aware controls - there are so few of those, that they put it in one BPL and it pulls ADO, BDE, DBX, SOAP and what else.

Comment: @Arioch'The I cannot abide all this "just in case" nonsense around Delphi. It's the same with modifications to the PATH environment variable. Delphi installer should not do that. And as for packages, if I want to use a package, I'll choose to do so. This sort of rubbish leads to folk taking dependencies on lord knows what. Yes they should know better, but let's make it a little harder for them to take accidental dependencies. And JEDI is the worst of the lot here with its millions of packages and monstrously bloated set of units. One small class costs you hundreds of extra units!

Comment: IntraWeb - usually installed with Delphi, almost no support. You can try to download newer version from Atozed. Soemtimes some bugs are fixed. Indy - http://www.indyproject.org/ and installed with delphi too. Dunno which one versin would be better for you. Istalliong vanilla version without cleansing stock version might be hard. JCL* come from http://jcl.sf.net however "DJcl" looks like **Design-time** package that in nop case is expected to be used/deployed with the app. Similarly jVcl.sf.net (installed after jcl). JvUIB is almost non-supported, look uib.sf.net for somewhat supported one.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan i am not the one who DID it, i just talk about some patterns i saw.

Comment: Rz252 is probably version 2.52 of http://raize.com TeeGL is *maybe* TeeChart or something else. Google tells that S403_r70 belonged to TurboPower Software, they closed long ago and given their stuff as open source - google for it. There probably is some fancy glamour stuff from iocomp.com/Products/ActiveXVCL/Default.aspx and for the rest, google and google. And the person who gave you that mess should have given you all the libraries needed, exactly the used versions of those. If he did not - make him do it now, before he forgot it all.

Comment: "Unfortunately no "runtime packages" in my dpr file " sure there is not. Maybe in .DOf file. What I said was to open the DPR project in IDE and go main menu -> View -> Project Options -> Runtime Packages

Comment: I think the OP is confusing Runtime Packages and units. He mentions red squiggly lines in the `Uses` clause.There could well be some custom code used in the project that isn't included in a component package.

Comment: @Andy_D - possible. But missing packages can also result in missed units

Comment: Most of the missing units I have right now seem to be part of the TMS component pack, I found some of them separately, but I cannot install them one by one as they have common parts and Delphi doesn't allow to install two parts with one or more of the same files. If I find a TMS component pack that I can install that would leave me only the ComPort (that could be part of iocomp2005, but that package is not findable) and one that probably has to do with some Genetec package, GXUIPROXYWEBLib_TLB

Comment: TLB means ocx active x import,  it is not about Delphi.  Cannot you get iocom at the link above?  Try to get tMS suite or move common units into a common BPL that all other packages will depend upon

Comment: So I found this TMS component pack. First it was version 6, but that seemed too new, in 5 I see classes I need like AdvOfficeStatusBar. When installing this component the red underlining didn't go away, then I saw that in tmsc2007.cbproj the line <None Include="AdvOfficeStatusBarReg.dcr"> was present, but in tmsc2009.cbrpoj it's <ResFiles Include="AdvOfficeStatusBarReg.dcr"> so i thought I needed a newer version of Delphi. Wrong! Now I get al these E2010 incompatible types as the main String type changed from Delphi 2007 to Delphi 2009

Comment: Unfortunately in RAD Studio 2009 I can at least compile or build the project, where in 2007 I have to click away dozens of error messages. But according to this char error in Sockets.pas I do need RAD Studio 2007, but how can I add classes like AdvOfficeStatusBar to that IDE if installing the TMS component pack is succesfull, but it still cannot find all those Adv*** includes afterwards? Should i manually change all the None into ResFiles? That seems a bit weird ...

Comment: There is a project aimed at catching up with Lazarus and enhancing packaging support. But since that is an opt-in voluntary solution, not enforced by Delphi itself, it would not help. But jsut for the record: http://owlyci.com/docs/tutorial/UsingIdeExpert

Comment: Usually source-level fix for Unicode in Delphi 2007/2009 boundary is straightforward, but very very tedious...

OTOH, since Delphi codegen is degrading which each new version, maybe you'd better avoid upgrading ? http://kazav.blogspot.ru/2014/01/delphi-2.html

Comment: For the record: The com port package A407_R90 belongs to [TurboPower Async Professional](https://sourceforge.net/projects/tpapro/) Version 4.07